# How to create higher order functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I have come across the array `forEach` function that is a higher order function and it takes only one parameter, *i.e.*, a closure. Now this closure internally loops through all the elements of the array one by one but does not return anything. The implementation of the closure is left to the choice of the user.

I have a custom class `MyClass` that has a private variable inside it `num` and a public function `setNum(num: Int)` to set the value of that private variable from outside. I am just trying to create a similar function `factorial` inside my custom class that takes only one parameter, *i.e.*, a closure. However, I have to manually call the closure inside `factorial`, pass the value of `num` as a parameter to the closure.

Is there a way that the closure can act on `num` without having passed it as a parameter? Basically I am just trying to replicate the array `forEach` function. Syntax of array `forEach` is:

```
array.forEach(body: (Int) -> Void) -> Void)
```

Implementation:

```
arr1.forEach { print($0) }
```

My code is as below:

```
import Foundation

public class MyClass {
    private var factorialNumber: Double = 0
    internal static var instance: MyClass?

    public func setFactorialNumber(number value: Double) {
        factorialNumber = value
    }

    public func factorial(body closure: (String?) -> Void) -> Void {
        var outputString: String?
        var result: Double = 1

        if factorialNumber <= 0 {
            outputString = nil
        } else {
            outputString = ""
            while(factorialNumber >= 1) {
                if factorialNumber == 1 {
                    outputString = outputString! +  "\(factorialNumber) = \(result)"
                    break
                } else {
                    outputString = outputString! + "\(factorialNumber) x "
                }
                result = result * factorialNumber
                factorialNumber -= 1
            }
        }

        // Finally closure call
        closure(outputString)
    }

    private init() {}

    public static func getInstance() -> MyClass {
        if self.instance == nil {
            self.instance = MyClass()
        }
        return self.instance!
    }
}
```

And here is how I have to call my function to calculate the factorial:

```
var obj1 = MyClass.getInstance()

obj1.setFactorialNumber(number: 5)
obj1.factorial{ (result) in
    print(result ?? "Factorial Result is Nil")
}
```

Please note that I have to pass a parameter `result` inside my closure to get the result of factorial.

Comment: It makes no sense to use a closure to calculate the factorial. The `forEach` function of `Array` has nothing in common with your needs for `factorial`.

Comment: wouldn't you want to reduce instead of foreach? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce

Comment: @vermau You have made mention of `MyClass` and `MyArray` but it appears they are one and the same. It seems `MyClass` is a typo and should be `MyArray`. And then `MyArray` is a very poor name for the class because that class has nothing to do with an array.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Please do not go on the name. This is just a practice thing. All I am trying to do is learn how to create higher order functions like array.forEach. My class and everything is just for practice. You can take the name of the class as MyArray, that is fine

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the question. You said "All I am trying to do is learn how to create higher order functions like array.forEach." But you've done that. What about `factorial` isn't a "higher order function like array.forEach?" What calling syntax did you want instead of the calling syntax you provide?

Comment: I have to pass "result" as a parameter to the closure inside my function "factorial" to get the result out and print on the screes. However in array.forEach function, there is no parameter passed to the closure. The closure is automatically accessing all the elements one by one from the array. So I am just thinking is there a way that my closure can also access the private variable "num" automatically and I don't have to pass "result" as a parameter to the closure.

Basically I want my function call to be like below:

func factorial { print("Factorial is \($0)") }

Comment: *"...  in array.forEach function, there is no parameter passed to the closure."* – I'm not sure what you mean. `arr1.forEach { print($0) }` is  a shorthand for `arr1.forEach { (elem)  in print(elem) }` and `elem` is the parameter passed to the closure.

Comment: @vermau I think you should edit the question to (a) make the existing code runnable (it's very close, but the small errors in names are confusing), and (b) show what code you *wish* would run but doesn't. As @martinr notes, I think what you want (`$0`) already works exactly as you want.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the reply. I have updated my code and removed MyArray and named it as MyClass and created an object of MyClass.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the reply. I have updated my code and removed MyArray and named it as MyClass and created an object of MyClass.

What I want to write is:

`obj1.factorial {
    print("Factorial is: \($0)")
}`

instead of:
`obj1.factorial { (result) in
    print("Factorial is: \(result)")
}`

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks a lot for the help. It got resolved. Thanks a ton once again

Comment: Visit this link for guide to create higher order function
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671941/how-to-create-higher-order-functions-in-swift>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that the closure can act on num without having passed it as a parameter? Basically I am just trying to replicate the array `forEach` function ... [And, in your comment:] All I am trying to do is learn how to create higher order functions like `array.forEach`.

It's hard to understand what you think you're after, but taking you at your word, let's write `forEach`. Here we go:

```
extension Sequence {
    func myForEach(f: (Element) -> ()) {
        for e in self {
            f(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
[1,2,3].myForEach { print($0) } // prints 1, then 2, then 3
```

We've done it! We wrote a higher-order function that acts exactly like `forEach`. So this must be how `forEach` actually works, more or less.

You can see from the example that it makes no sense to ask not to have to pass a parameter into the function that our `forEach` takes as a parameter. That is exactly what we *must* be able to do in order for that function to have an element to operate on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt for the explanation. I am also doing excatly the same in my function "factorial". Then when I call "factorial" from the code, why do I have to pass "result" to get the output and print it on the screen. Why cant I use $0 to print the output. I want my function to be like this:

obj1.factorial {
    print("Factorial is: \($0)")
}

But I have to write:

obj1.factorial { (result) in 
    print("Factorial is: \(result)")
}

Comment: Then write it. After all, `result in ... result` and `$0` are just two ways of saying the same thing. Looks to me like you just forgot the backslash. `obj1.factorial { print("Factorial is: \($0)") }`

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks a lot for the help. It got resolved. Thanks a ton once again.